# A Power BI measure that displays whether a quarter is an actual or estimate

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am working to create a measure in Power BI that will allow me to track whether each quarter in the fiscal year is in work or complete.

Right now, I have a measures  that calculate:

1. Fiscal Quarter of each month in my table (My fiscal year is 10/1-9/31)

   ```
   Quarters = if(Month([Date]) >= 10, "Q1",  if(Month([Date]) <= 3, "Q2",
   if(Month([Date]) <= 6, "Q3",  "Q4")))
   ```
2. Current Fiscal Quarter

   ```
   current Quarter = if(Month(TODAY()) >= 10, "Q1", if(Month(TODAY()) < 4, "Q2",
   if(Month(TODAY()) < 7, "Q3", "Q4")))
   ```
3. Current Month

   ```
   Current Month = MONTH(TODAY())
   ```

I want a calculated column or measure that does the following:

Basically, if a quarter is still in progress, the measure should display `Q_ - Estimate`, and if the quarter is complete or has not yet begun, it should display `Q_ - Actual`

So for example, we are in quarter 4 right now, so the measure should display `Q4 - Estimate` for Q4, and `Q1 - Actual`, `Q2 - Actual`, and `Q3 - Actual` since Q1-Q3 are complete. 
The end goal is to have these labels on the x-axis for the following graph:

[image: x-axis quarter example]

I have attempted some IF statements, but keep getting stuck since each quarter must assume one of two values.

I want the following:

`IF([current quarter] = "Q4", "Q4 - Estimate", "Q4 - Actual")`... but for every quarter.

Is it possible to accomplish this in one IF statement? If not, how might I tackle this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
[column] = IF([Quarters]=[current quarter],[Quarters] & " - estimate",[Quarters] & " - Actual")
```